# UISwitch в AccessoryView в UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone, uitableview

Всем привет! Подскажите, у меня есть UISwitch с измененным размером и при вставке в AccessoryView в UITableViewCell он уплывает вверх и не становится по середине, а если не изменять размер, то всё ок. Но мне очень надо изменить. Вот код:

```
switchButton = [UISwitch new];
_switchButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.77, 0.64);
[_switchButton setOnTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedSegmentedControlColor"]]];


self.accessoryView = _switchButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поставить точку привязки, перед уменьшением

```
switchButton = [UISwitch new];
_switchButton.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
_switchButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.77, 0.64);
[_switchButton setOnTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedSegmentedControlColor"]]];

self.accessoryView = _switchButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй изменить так:

```
_switchButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f);
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуй поставить switchButton на ячейку и не использовать accessoryView для этого.
Да, может потребоваться сделать сабкласс для ячейки или еще как-то изменить размер ее вьюшек